# Is a `readonly` `input` considered interactive content?

Tags: html

### Context

According to the [HTML spec for an `a` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-a-element):

> ...there must be no interactive content descendant

According to the [HTML spec for interactive content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#interactive-content):

> Interactive content is content that is specifically intended for user interaction.
>
> `input` (if the `type` attribute is not in the **Hidden** state)

According to the [HTML spec for an `input` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element):

> If the `type` attribute is not in the Hidden state: Interactive content.

According to the [HTML spec for the `input` element's `readonly` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-readonly):

> The `readonly` attribute is a boolean attribute that controls whether or not the user can edit the form control. When specified, the element is not mutable.

### Question

Is a `text` `input` with the `readonly` attribute considered interactive content?

For example:

```
<a href="/foo">Foo</a>
  <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="foo" value="foo">
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the input even with read-only is still an interactive component, either because the read-only is temporary and the input element will be fully interactive, or because you have it to deliberately provide information the user is going to interact with E.G copy to clipboard.

Interactivity in HTML is if the user is able to do anything with it to affect there use of the site by default, as such an A is interactive because it directs them to another part of the site.

Anything that is interactive (by default) is not allowed to have another interactive (by default) thing inside it because without Javascript intervening and sorting out wich interaction to handle it "could" have different behaviors between browsers.

as hinted to above Javascript can change this, E.G a none interactive element (by default) such as a div, span, ul, li, and such could all be made interactive by Javascript and as such Javascript code is responsible for making sure their interactions are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and confirming my suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

As the spec is written, I think an `input` with the `readonly` attribute is considered interactive content. I think the only time an `input` element isn't considered interactive content is when the `type` attribute is `hidden`.

For example:

```
<a href="/foo">Foo</a>
  <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="foo" value="foo">
</a>
```